# How to show the onboarding view as a sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to show my onboarding view as a sheet. Is there anyone here who can help me?

Here's how it looks right now:
[image: Onboarding]

I want it to be displayed as a sheet from top to bottom. I tried to do it, but it doesn't work. Is there a solution to this?

Here's the code:

### Login view

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("needsAppOnboarding") private var needsAppOnboarding: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .sheet(isPresented: $needsAppOnboarding) {
                OnboardingView()
            }
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

### OnboardingView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Spacer()
                Image("wulkanowy-svg")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .top)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("OnboardingColor"))
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("onboarding.description.title")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Text("onboarding.description.content")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                Spacer()
                OnboardingButtonView()
                    .padding()
            }
    }
}

struct WulkanowyCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            OnboardingView().previewLayout(.fixed(width: 320, height: 640))
        }
    }
}
```

### OnboardingButtonView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingButtonView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("needsAppOnboarding") var needsAppOnboarding: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            needsAppOnboarding = false
        }, label: {
            Text("onboarding.continue")
        })
        .padding(10)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color("OnboardingColor"))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.title)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}

struct OnboardingButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingButtonView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Comment: `needsAppOnboarding` is false so you don't see any presented sheet.

Comment: At which moment: on appear or on button click?

Comment: Okay, yes. I forgot that i set it to false. It works right now! Thanks for help.